# setwd() results in a syntax error in Terminal

Tags: r, terminal, cron, syntax-error

**Why is it that the RScript works fine on RStudio but results in an error when running the crontab job on Terminal?**

I'm trying to run a crontab job on an RScript to collect data every minute (* * * * *). The RScript works fine when run on RStudio however when running the crontab, I get the following error:

```
/Users/xx/Capstone_2/Get_Data.R: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `'/Users/xx/Capstone_2/Data''
/Users/xx/Capstone_2/Get_Data.R: line 3: `setwd('/Users/xx/Capstone_2/Data')'
```

Here is what I run on `crontab -e`:

`* * * * * /Users/xx/Capstone_2/Get_Data.R`

Here is the RScript:

```
setwd('/Users/xx/Capstone_2/Data')
library(twitteR)

setup_twitter_oauth('consumer-key', 'consumer-secret', 
'access-token','access-secret')

iphonex <- searchTwitter("iphonex", n=1000)
iphonex <- twListToDF(iphonex)

write.csv(iphonex, '/Users/xx/Capstone_2/Data/iphonex.csv')
```

Comment: What error message occurs when this code is executed via crontab? Is it possible that the userid with which the cron job is executed does not have write access to the subdirectory listed in `write.csv()`?

Comment: Wild guess: Try using double quotes instead of single quotes in the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shown us all of the `/Users/xx/Capstone_2/Get_Data_Test.R` file, then the problem is that the shell doesn't know you want to run it through R.  You need to add

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
```

as the first line.

Comment: I added that line but I get a different error: `/bin/sh: /Users/xx/Capstone_2/Get_Data_Test.R: /usr/bin/Rscript: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: Where is R installed?  You can use the console command `which Rscript` to find it.  Use the path to Rscript in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:**

Check (in terminal) where Rscript is installed using:

```
which Rscript
```

**Step-2:**

Adapt the shebang line in your R script, according to path of step-1 (e.g.):

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
```

**Step-3:**

Let crontab handle the change to the directory where you have your R script.

```
* * * * * cd /Users/xx/Capstone_2/ && /usr/bin/Rscript Get_Data.R
```